# table Laws_Table has no column named Category_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: java, android

i have made three list by clicking on the element of 1 list it automatically moved to other. 1st list have 3 values by clicking on 1st value of 1st list there is no error similarly by clicking on 1st and 2nd values of 2nd and third list there is no error but clicking on third value their raise an error and list is empty on out put.

i have change the other of table from which it is getting data

```
package com.ayesha.judicial_provision;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="JD_PROVISION_DB";
    private  static final int DataBase_Version=1;

    ///////////LAWSDB////////////
    public static final String LAW_TABLE_NAME="Laws_Table";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String Key_Category="Category_Name";
    public static final String key_Sub_Category="Sub_Category_name";
    public static final String LAW_Name="Law_name";
    public static final String Key_Law_Number="Law_number";
    public static final String KEY_Subject="subject";
    public static final String Key_Description="Description";
    public static final String Key_Condition="Condition";
    public static final String Key_Panelty="Panelty";

    public static final String Key_Date="Date";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {


        ///////LAWSDB/////////

        String CREATE_TABLE7="CREATE TABLE "+LAW_TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+Key_Category+" TEXT, "+key_Sub_Category+" TEXT," +
                ""+Key_Law_Number+" TEXT, "+LAW_Name+" TEXT, "+KEY_Subject+" TEXT, "+Key_Description+" TEXT," +
                " "+Key_Condition+" TEXT, "+Key_Panelty+" TEXT, "+Key_Date+" TEXT )";

        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE7);
        Log.d("Table ",CREATE_TABLE7);

      @override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS JD_PROVISION_DB"+LAW_TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);

    }

    // laws



    public void addFemaleProtectionLaws(Context c){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Key_Category,"FemaleProtectionAct");
        cv.put(key_Sub_Category,"Spreading False Information");
        cv.put(KEY_Name," False Information ");
        cv.put(KEY_Subject,"Spreading False Information about an Individual");
        cv.put(Key_Description,"Whoever intentionally and publicly displays any" +
                " information through any information system,"+
                " which he knows to be false and intimidates or " +
                "harms the reputation or privacy of a natural person.");
        cv.put(Key_Panelty,"up to 3 Years in Prison or up to Rs. 1 Million in Fine or both");
        db.insert(LAW_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        Toast.makeText(c, "Data is inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        db.close();
    }


    }

}
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Laws_Table has no
>   column named Category_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:
>   INSERT INTO
>   Laws_Table(Category_name,Description,Category,Sub_Category_name,subject,Panelty)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your SQL insert statement uses "Category_name" with a lower case "n" but your create table statement creates a table with "Category_Name" using uppercase "N".

Ensure that database API you're using doesn't take into account the case of the column names. Sometimes queries need to be case sensitive. Let me know if this doesn't fix it.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't delete the previous database. Uninstall then run it again, let me know if problem persists. I do not see any obvious errors in the create table SQL, although I think you're missing a closing curly brace before the onUpgrade method. Make sure that you add this "}"

Comment: solved the error thanks for your time and consideration!!

Comment: If my response answered your question, please mark it as the accepted response so that others may see it if they run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think you should delete the database you have created previously and modified again... I am using react-native and i changed my database column then i ran into the same problem but the problem is resolved once i deleted the database and recreated it.
just like Dustin said.

Comment: Isn't your advice the same like in the already 4 years ago accepted answer?